# Не получается передать json массив в ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь передать простой json массив в ajax data. Написано сейчас следующее:

```
var dop = {};

dop['age'] = $('#age').val();
dop['come_date'] = $('#come_date').val();
dop['out_date'] = $('#out_date').val();

$.ajax({
    url:"/обработчик.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    data : JSON.stringify(dop),
    error : errorHandler,
    success: function(data){
        alert("Заработало");
    }
});
```

Если просто вывожу массив получившийся через alert(JSON.stringify(dop)); то выглядит примерно вот так.

```
{"age":"41","come_date":"2017-05-24","out_date":"2017-09-25"}
```

Вроде выглядит всё верно, но массив не передается в data, скрипт просто не срабатывает. При вбивке вручную данных и инициализации переменных как ниже, всё работает

```
var age = $('#age').val();
var come_date = $('#come_date').val();
var out_date  = $('#out_date').val();

$.ajax({
   url:"/обработчик.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType : 'json',
   data: {'age': age,'come_date': come_date,'out_date': out_date},
   error : errorHandler,
   success: function(data){
        alert("Заработало");
   }
});
```

Так понимаю проблема в форматировании JSON массива?

Comment: `data: dop,` `alert("Заработало");` - **t**

Comment: "скрипт просто не срабатывает" - какой скрипт?

Comment: Ну то бишь при наличии массива через data: JSON.stringify(dop) просто ничего не происходит, не выводится ни ошибка, ни отправка в php скрипт.

Comment: "ничего не происходит" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: Ну раз success и error ничего не выводят, то наверно до них дело просто не доходит. Ошибок при этом в консоли при отправке нет.

Comment: `data: {'age': age,'come_date': come_date,'out_date': out_date'},` - это не может работать, лишняя кавычка

Comment: `success` ничего не выводит, потому что в javascript-е нет функции `aler`

Comment: Исправил опечатку в посте. В любом случае, немного не понял вашу структуру в 1 комментарии.

Comment: `error : errorHandler` - у вас `errorHandler` имеется?

Comment: Я просто взял вырезку из кода, функция имеется и работает, если вы об этом.

Comment: А почему именно JSON? Вы же формируете массив и затем переводите в JSON. А в принимающем скрипте поди декодируете JSON и работаете как с массивом?

Comment: напишите  `$.ajax({ ..., data: dop, error: function(){console.log("ERROR");}, success: function(){console.log("SUCCESS");}});` и посмотрите, что появится в консоли браузера

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Лишний раз перемудрил с использованием JSON.stringify.

Comment: да напишите вы ему, что не надо делать `JSON.stringify` перед отправкой.

Comment: @teran - я уже несколько раз это написал

Comment: @Igor явным текстом ни разу. я видел ответ в первом комменте, естественно, но автор явно не сообразил к чему это написано.